# How to add fluid simulation to an animation in blender?

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation

so I've made an animation of some characters rotating along an axis, and I want to add a fluid simulation at a certain point in the animation. At around 240 frames in. Basically I've got a model of a seed character, and I've animated him and I want a simulated drop of water to land on him at a point later in the animation. How would I go about doing this? I have the blend file if anyone is interested in helping me out. Thanks :)

Comment: If it's a **single drop** you don't need to simulate fluid, physics may be useful though.